# Expressing output in processing algorithms

Tags: pyqgis-3

In the following code, a KML file is created on the output path:

'''
# Save vector features to file
alg_params = {
'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS': '',
'INPUT': parameters['inputlayer'],
'LAYER_NAME': '',
'LAYER_OPTIONS': '',
'OUTPUT':   'F:/QGis3_Models/SHP2KML/Linhas.KML'
}
outputs['SaveVectorFeaturesToFile'] = processing.run('native:savefeatures',  alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
return results
'''

However, if I define the same path trough a string variable like *filename_KML*,

'''
myfilepath= self.parameterDefinition('inputlayer').valueAsPythonString(parameters['inputlayer'], context)
print (myfilepath)

```
    filename_KML = (myfilepath.replace(".shp", ".KML"))
    print (filename_KML)

    # Save vector features to file
    alg_params = {
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS': '',
        'INPUT': parameters['inputlayer'],
        'LAYER_NAME': '',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS': '',
        'OUTPUT':   filename_KML
    }
    outputs['SaveVectorFeaturesToFile'] = processing.run('native:savefeatures',  alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    return results
```

'''

I will receive the following error message:
*Could not create layer 'F:/QGis3_Models/SHP2KML/Linhas.KML'.gpkg: Creation of data source failed (OGR error: sqlite3_open('F:/QGis3_Models/SHP2KML/Linhas.KML'.gpkg) failed: unable to open database file)*

Note: print(filename_KML) = 'F:/QGis3_Models/SHP2KML/Linhas.KML'

Here is the full code:

'''

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
import processing
from qgis.utils import iface

class Kml2shp(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('inputlayer', 'Input layer', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint,QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine,QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
    # overall progress through the model
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
    results = {}
    outputs = {}

    myfilepath= self.parameterDefinition('inputlayer').valueAsPythonString(parameters['inputlayer'], context)
    print (myfilepath)
    
    filename_KML = (myfilepath.replace(".shp", ".KML"))
    print (filename_KML)

    # Save vector features to file
    alg_params = {
        'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS': '',
        'INPUT': parameters['inputlayer'],
        'LAYER_NAME': '',
        'LAYER_OPTIONS': '',
        'OUTPUT':   filename_KML
    }
    outputs['SaveVectorFeaturesToFile'] = processing.run('native:savefeatures',  alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    return results

def name(self):
    return 'KML2SHP'

def displayName(self):
    return 'KML2SHP'

def group(self):
    return 'Same'

def groupId(self):
    return 'Same'

def createInstance(self):
    return Kml2shp()
```

'''

Comment: Already solved! Just make   re.sub("[\"\']", "", filename_KML)